# Jenkins / Hudson automatically permute parameter values of parameterized builds

Tags: jenkins, hudson, build-process, build-automation, jenkins-plugins

I have a parameterized build that has some options as to how to build the project. For example:

- color: red, green or blue
- package: yes, no

Since this list is likely to grow and I would like to be notified which configuration specifically broke I'd like Jenkins to build all variants of this build. So that after each checkin it executes the build with all available colors and each color with and without packaging.

Is there something like this? Specifically I'd like to avoid creating a new job for each configuration of the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins has matrix projects, see [the wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project). They do exactly what you want and more.

Comment: Doh! I found that one too ca. 2 minutes after hitting submit. Thanks a lot!